# Start spring-restdocs locally

Tags: gradle, springdoc, spring-restdocs

I want to run this project locally:

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs
```

I cloned the project locally and I run `./gradlew asciidoctor` successfully.

But now how I can run the project locally?

Comment: What do you mean by "run the project locally"? Spring REST Docs is a library that you use when testing your application to produce documentation for the application's  RESTful API. As such, it can't be run on its own. The Gradle command that you have used has just built the project's own reference documentation.

Comment: Let me ask this way: How to build the project locally and start it so that I can open web pages into my web browser located into the project?

Comment: Other than its reference documentation, there are no such pages in the project. After running `./gradlew asciidoctor`, the reference documentation is available at `docs/build/docs/asciidoc/index.html`.